# Informix Accent Insensitive Search

Tags: sql, informix, diacritics

Is there any way (a function, a config option, etc.) to force informix to ignore accents on searches?

Example:

```
select id, name from user where name like 'conceição%'
```

Returns:

```
1    |    conceicao oliveira
2    |    conceiçao santos
3    |    conceicão andrade
4    |    conceição barros
```

Thanks

Comment: Which flavor (IDS, XPS) and version of Informix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, that I'm aware of. You could install the [Regex DataBlade module](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/db_regexp.html). The use it's [regexp_match](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/db_regexp.html#regexp_match) function. Replacing the query with something like this:

```
where regexp_match(name , 'concei[çc][ãa][o]%')
```

Or, if you don't have that option, what I would do would be add another 'normalized_name' column. replacing all the accented characters with a "standard" character. Then query my table based on that.

> name='conceiçao santos',  normalized_name='conceicao santos'

Adding a normalized column will also make sure you're not dependant on any module, or any particular database for that matter.

Comment: We thought about using a normalized column but due to the size of the system and the number of columns that would have to be done, it's a last resource option. I just found that Informix has a MATCHES clause, similar to LIKE, that I could use to do what you suggested with regexp_match and that's what we will probably use. Still, it's going to be a lot of work to change all queries, and it would be wonderful if Informix had a global option for accent insensitive search

Comment: I missed that part about the MATCHES operator. And it's built in.

Comment: It DOES have Global language support (GLS), but I don't think it'll do what you need it to do.

Comment: I developed an isql app for pawnshops in Puerto Rico. I upshifted all alpha data entry and used English charecter set to avoid problems with queries, collating sequence and having to press extra keys! The isql 4.10 didn't have GLS, isql would cough if it encountered non-English chars! Using English also simplifies things, its the global business language!